# UPDATE a field in a separate TABLE from a SELECT query on a separate TABLE

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that gives me Inventory Dollars by Vendor for the Current Month.  I have an `Inventory_Summary` table that I keep historical data in.  I want the query to be able to update the most current month's data in the `Inventory_Summary` table.  Here is the query to pull the Inventory data that needs to go into the `Inventory_Summary` table.

```
SELECT 
    Vendor,
    SUM(Cost*QOH) AS InvDlr
FROM
    dbo.Inventory
WHERE
    Division NOT IN ('9999')
AND
    Class NOT IN ('5500')
AND
    Vendor IN ('AA','BB','CC','DD','EE')
GROUP BY
    Vendor
```

The table I need this result set to go into is structured like this:

```
Inventory_Summary

Vendor
Vendor_Name
MonthNum
Year
InvDlr
```

How can I UPDATE the most recent data daily for the current month?

Comment: Have you any date column in your inventory table for last modified date?

Comment: For month and year, assuming just today's date (i.e., when the query is run)?  Also, is `MonthNum` 1-based, i.e., 1-12?  It looks like also you may be updating multiple rows at once, for each vendor?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server?  If so, please tag it as such with the version.

Comment: I will run the query daily, so whatever the value is for that time is fine.  The MonthNum value is 1 = January, 2 = February, 3 = March, 4 = April etc.

Comment: Will your script also insert automatically (instead of update) when it becomes a new month?  Or will it always be updating?  Also, you don't seem to have anywhere in your query where you are filtering for the current month in your SELECT?  Are these cumulative totals?

Comment: I will add a new month when it occurs.  The data in Inventory is just the current month's data.  The values are as of that day I run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing an `UPDATE` from one table to another is fairly straightforward, using the pattern of `UPDATE Table SET fields FROM Joined Tables`:

```
UPDATE S
SET S.InvDlr = I.InvDlr
FROM (SELECT 
          Vendor,
          SUM(Cost*QOH) AS InvDlr
      FROM
          dbo.Inventory
      WHERE
          Division NOT IN ('9999')
      AND
          Class NOT IN ('5500')
      AND
          Vendor IN ('AA','BB','CC','DD','EE')
      GROUP BY
          Vendor) I
JOIN Inventory_Summary S on I.Vendor = S.Vendor
WHERE S.MonthNum = MONTH(GETDATE())
  AND S.Year = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

In this example, I've simply dropped the `SELECT` you provided in a subquery and given it an alias of `I`.  Then this is joined to `Inventory_Summary` by the `Vendor` field.  Finally, the `InvDlr` field is set to the amount in the subquery.  Also, the `Inventory_Summary` table is filtered for only current month and year.

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e663/1 (I left `Division` and `Class` fields out, but that should not affect the demo).

Comment: That deleted my MonthNum data for value of '4'

Comment: I believe it was because I had MonthNum and Year and text and not numeric fields.

Comment: You can convert numeric to text relatively easily: `CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))`.  And vice versa: `CAST(S.MonthNum AS INTEGER)`.